# How do I select all elements with the same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building this game with JavaScript. It's a simple game: you get asked what number1 + number2 equals, and you have 4 different options to choose (only one answer is correct).

I have 4 different divs for the 4 different options, all with the class '.field-block'. This is what I tried doing:

```
var choice = document.querySelector('.field-block');
choice.addEventListener('click', getChoice);

function getChoice(){
   if(choice.innerHTML != result){
    after.classList.remove('hide');
    after.classList.add('wrong');
    after.innerHTML = 'Ooh you were wrong ! Play again to give it another shot !';
  } else{
    after.classList.remove('hide');
    after.classList.add('correct');
    after.innerHTML = "Good job ! Don't be affraid to try again :)";
  }
}
```

However, by doing this I'm only able to click on the first 'field-block' divs and not on the other ones.

Here is the full codepen of my project:

https://codepen.io/teenicarus/pen/Oxaaoe

How do I select all divs, so that the user can click on all of them and not just the first one ?

I appreciate all responses

Comment: Is this supposed to be multiple choice? I can't tell if you mean you can only select the first one because of the permanent overlay or what...

Comment: @ProEvilz yes it's supposed to be multiple choice. On my project for some reason you can only click on the first div. If you try to click on the other divs, it doesn't work

Comment: when you select a wrong answer and you get the oh you were wrong message, what is supposed to happen then?

Comment: That's because `.querySelector` returns the first element matching the CSS selector you give it. try `document.getElementsByClassName('field-block');`

Comment: @ProEvilz normally you're supposed to click on the 'play again' button that refreshes the page and gives you another question. However, I want to make sure the choices work correctly first, like I said at the moment you can only choose the first one as an anwser

Comment: Am I missing something here? How are you guys able to figure this out. When I click an answer, I get the 'wrong answer' message and you can't do **anything** from that point on. You have to reload the page...

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because `querySelector()` returns a single item. Use `querySelectorAll()` to retrieve all instances. You can then loop through them:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.field-block').forEach(function(field) {
  field.addEventListener('click', function() {
    getChoice(this);
  });
})

function getChoice(choice){
   if (choice.innerHTML != result) {
     after.classList.remove('hide');
     after.classList.add('wrong');
     after.innerHTML = 'Ooh you were wrong ! Play again to give it another shot !';
  } else {
     after.classList.remove('hide');
     after.classList.add('correct');
     after.innerHTML = "Good job ! Don't be afraid to try again :)";
  }
}
```

Comment: **document.querySelectorAll**

Comment: @Vitaly Thanks. Wrote it in the description but forgot to update the code example :)

Answer (score 1):

> However, by doing this I'm only able to click on the first
>   'field-block' divs and not on the other ones.

`querySelector` returns only one element, you need to use `querySelectorAll`

```
var choices = document.querySelectorAll('.field-block');
[].slice.call(choices).forEach( function( choice ){ //iterate and assign event handler to them individually
   choice.addEventListener('click', function(){
      getChoice(choice);
   });
});

function getChoice(choice){
   if(choice.innerHTML != result){
    after.classList.remove('hide');
    after.classList.add('wrong');
    after.innerHTML = 'Ooh you were wrong ! Play again to give it another shot !';
  } else{
    after.classList.remove('hide');
    after.classList.add('correct');
    after.innerHTML = "Good job ! Don't be affraid to try again :)";
  }
}
```

Or more **simpler version in jquery**

```
$('.field-block').click( function(){
  getChoice( this );
});
```